# Launch script after SFTP disconnect

Tags: linux-mint, sftp, nautilus

I'm currently using Caja (basically the same as Nautilus) to connect using SSH to my server and work with files. What I'm looking for is a way to launch a simple script when I disconnect - I can launch a script after disconnecting from the TTY by putting it into ~/.bash_logout file, but that is not executed when disconnecting from a file manager. The only idea I have is to set up a cronjob which would be checking for existing sftp-server or sshd processes periodicaly and launched the script when there's no such process running. Is there any easier way to do this?